# Look out. There's a spammer about

Tags: discussion, spam

**I have seen a particular spammer abusing various sites on the Internet - now he has set his sites on StackExchange.com - I urge all to be on alert.**

If you really want to see stuff about him, the sites he's abused, and the sort of material he promotes, look at the edit history on this question.

Comment: I turned the larger image into a link, I think your post is effective without having it immediately visible. Thanks for the heads-up, while we deal with this sort of person pretty much the same, we can probably kick him out quicker if he's identified.

Comment: I feel like your question is _alarmingly_ detailed and almost reads like a reverse psychology advertisement _for_ this individual. Your heart is probably in the right place, but there is no need to link to everything he has done, founded and written _before_ he has even done any actual wrongdoing on the site, making a cross post in the process; it's just click bait. Please be careful.

Comment: @badp - Point taken. I leave it to Tim and those in charge of these things to do what's appropriate. If I was too zealous, Tim can correct it. The main thing is that the message has been received.

Comment: @badp I think what you're picking up on here is the OP's sense of desperation, chasing _very_ toxic individuals out of a community can be really hard, and extremely frustrating. I can recall a few recent encounters where having some advanced background would have helped, so this is appreciated. But - of course, take it at face value and _don't_ give the person any undue attention - that's like turning on a bug light that reads WELCOME.

Comment: @TimPost - feel free to edit or change the post however you deem appropriate - my work is done.

Comment: I appreciate OP's desperation, but right now, the chief function of this post is to increase exposure of the spammer's web presence. Could we please edit this down so that it includes no links thereto? I don't think we really need to even have anything about the identity or characteristics of the spammer, as spam is pretty self-evident when it appears, and we tend to catch it as such pretty quickly, regardless of who posts it.

Comment: @ComeAndGo Why include his picture? If any of us encounter him it will be with an online persona, not his physical being. I don't see how his picture will assist in identification.

Comment: @DoubleAA - because he generally use that picture as his avatar. That's how I got it.

Comment: I deleted all names, pictures, URLs, and site titles from this post. I see zero benefit and nonzero harm from our giving links and eyeballs to these identifiers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Far more 'interesting' personalities have attempted to disrupt the network with this sort of nonsense, this prompted us to put a system into place that quickly shuts them up. Make sure that you:

- Flag their posts as SPAM and do not interact with them in any other way
- (For mods) Destroy the account as 'created for spam or nonsense' quickly
- (Optionally) flag one of the posts as 'other' to indicate that you've identified this person (so that we can modulate the shields with his resonant frequency so that his posts disintegrate)

Should he appear, and post that sort of drivel, I will personally see to it that he's met with an overwhelming and resounding:

***........... AND STAY OUT.***

As the door hits him in the proverbial derriere on the way out. We built the new system *precisely* with this sort of use case in mind, so we're more than ready to deal with it.

Remember, nipping him here also guarantees he's nipped across the network - the spam system is a global thing.